# Does Windows (Active Directory) kerberos use DNS for Realm mapping?

Tags: windows, kerberos

Will Windows clients use DNS to map hosts to specific kerberos realms?

Specifically, do they use `_kerberos.host.example.com IN TXT OTHERREALM.COM` records?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows clients only use SRV DNS records (and can fail back to NetBIOS-based discovery) to locate domain services, not TXT records.

I don't want to go in to too much detail about realm trusts and interoperability between Windows clients, AD domain controllers, and non-Microsoft KDCs because you don't say what exactly you're trying to accomplish... but you can specify non-Microsoft KDCs in the registry of your Windows clients in `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\Kerberos\Domains\KdcNames = kdc.otherrealm.com`

Comment: I'm using Group Policy instead of the Registry. I was just hoping I could use DNS like I do on the linux side. Just one more thing to keep track of.

Comment: This absolutely does not answer the question. It was not about service but about mapping host names to Kerberos realms as in `krb5.conf` is done manually if `TXT` is not used.

Comment: What @Michael-O said.  It's maybe a good answer except it's for the wrong question!  I don't know why it was upvoted so much.

Comment: Alright well apparently I did not understand the question, and if the OP wants to unaccept this answer, I'll delete it.